# how can I access my server from outside of my lan?

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding, webserver, home-server

I set up my own debian server at home and I can connect to it via ssh from any computer in my lan, but if I try to do it with my phone ( when using mobile data and not Wi-Fi) it does not work.

When I try using the browser to connect to my server, it times out and says it can not connect to that address.

I went to my router and enabled port forwarding. I set up port range 20-80(so either ssh or http requests ) to forward to 192.168.1.129 (my server ip) and still I get nothing when I enter my external ip address in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To connect from outside your own LAN, you need

a) The external IP address provided by your ISP, which is NOT 192.168.1.129 - that's a [non-routing address](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_nonroutable_IP_address), and can only be seen from inside your LAN. Use [ipchicken.com](http://ipchicken.com/) or similar sites, and find what your external IP address is.  ISPs often change those frequently, so check shortly before you leave.  The only way you can get a fixed IP external IP address from your ISP is to pay for it, and ISPs charge a pretty penny. Alternatively, you can use a [Dynamic DNS Service](http://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-remote-access-for-computer-with-dynamic-ip/) to translate for you.

b) Open ports through the firewall of your ISP's [gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem#Residential_Gateways), or if they only provide a [modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem#Broadband), then the firewall in the [router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)) the modem connects to. However, leaving a port open is risky, as rogue PCs on botnets are always searching for open ports, so have the firewall use a non-standard port, and [forward those ports' traffic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) to the standard port you have open on your server, using the router's or gateway's instructions.